# Azure Pipelines, dynamic number of steps based on variable output of previous job

Tags: azure-pipelines

I'm trying to create a dynamic number of steps, based on the output value of a variable set in a previous job.

```yaml
- stage: deploy
  jobs:
    - job: A
      steps:
      - bash: |
          echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=myOutputVar;isoutput=true]this is a list"
        name: passOutput
    - job: B
      dependsOn: A
      variables:
        myVarFromJobA: $[ dependencies.A.outputs['passOutput.myOutputVar'] ]  
      steps:
      - ${{ each env in split(variables.myVarFromJobA, ' ')}}:
        - script: echo "${{env}}"
```

When job `A` runs, the environment has `myVarFromJobA` set to `this is a list` correctly. However, I can't get a the template expression to evaluate based on the the variables new value. Instead, it does a `split` on the literal value of `$[ dependencies.A.outputs['passOutput.myOutputVar'] ]`, rather than `this is a list`.

Answer (score 0):

Because the "${{}}" is compile time expression, so it cannot evaluate the variable from previous job. For more information, you could refer to [Runtime expression syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#runtime-expression-syntax).

If you want to split the variable, you could try to use the PowerShell script:

```
steps:
- task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      # Write your PowerShell commands here.
      echo $(myVarFromJobA)
      $results = "$(myVarFromJobA)".split(" ")
      foreach ($var in $results){
        Write-Host $var
      }
```